# Google Maps API does'nt work on another devices

Tags: javascript, php, apache, xampp, localhost

I tried to access my local website that show a map to gain the coordinates with google maps API, somehow when I access my local website on other devices such as smartphone the map and the coordinates didn't show up. I'm using apache XAMPP, can someone explain how suppose I do to solve this?

Sorry for my bad english

I tried to configre my httpd-files on XAMPP for gaining acces for my local website on smartphone but still, didn't show any progress.

Comment: may be related to the configuration of your local server or API key you are using isn't properly configured to work on different devices.